# C# tasks with dynamic delay

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task, async-await

I have a function that needs to process items 3 at a time, and if the total time taken is less than x seconds, the thread should sleep for the remaining seconds before proceeding further.

So I'm doing the following:

```
    private void ProcessItems()
    {
        for (int i = 0, n = items.Count; i < n; i++)
        {
            Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
            stopwatch.Start();

            batch.Add(items[i]);

            if (batch.Count == 3 || i >= items.Count - 3)
            {
                List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(3);

                foreach (Item item in batch)
                    tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ProcessItem(item)));

                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

                batch.Clear();
            }

            stopwatch.Stop();

            int elapsed = (int)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            int delay = (3000) - elapsed;

            if (delay > 0)
                Thread.Sleep(delay);
        }
    }
```

The ProcessItem function makes a webrequest and processes the response (callback). This is the function that takes a small amount of time.

However, if I understand tasks correctly, a thread can have multiple tasks. Therefore, if I sleep the thread, other tasks can be affected.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve the above, and can tasks be used within Parallel.Foreach?

Comment: any final solution with full source code working about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks run on automatically managed threads. There is nothing intrinsically wrong with blocking a thread. It is just a little wasteful.

Here is how I would implement this very cleanly:

```
MyItem[] items = ...;
foreach(MyItem[] itemsChunk in items.AsChunked(3)) {
 Parallel.ForEach(itemsChunk, item => Process(item));
 //here you can insert a delay
}
```

This wastes not a single thread and is trivially simple. `Parallel.ForEach` used the current thread to process work items as well, so it does not sit idle. You can add your delay logic as well. Implementing [`AsChunked`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15414467/122718) is left as an exercise for the reader... This function is supposed to split a list into chunks of the given size (3). The good thing about such a helper function is that it untangles the batching logic from the important parts.

Comment: Yes. If you do not want to burn a thread for that, use `await Task.Delay`. That forces the entire async model on you, though. You must change all callers to use Task as well. If you have few threads it does not matter from a perf standpoint which model you chose because a thread has constant overhead. It does not make the stuff that runs on it slower or faster compared to async. I recommend against using async if you don't need it because it complicates stuff.

Comment: How does await Task.Delay fit in your example then?

Comment: You insert `await Task.Delay(3000)` in the marked spot, mark the method `async`, change the return type to `Task` and now have to change all callers to await that returned task. I think you should research a bit how async works, and then decide whether you need that or not. Probably: not. Are you concerned about a specific problem?

Comment: So await Task.Delay(3000) returns an empty task that waits for 3000 then?

Comment: @Ivan-MarkDebono No, `Task.Delay()` returns a `Task` that waits for the given time, `await Task.Delay()` asynchronously waits for that time.

Comment: What is AsChunked ? implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Task.Delay
```

instead

```
    static async Task DoSomeProcess()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }
```

You are right, Thread.Sleep would block other tasks

Yes you can pair async/await pattern with Parallel.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ProcessItems` method can be very easily transformed into async version `ProcessItemsAsync` (I didn't validate the "batching" logic):

```
private async Task ProcessItemsAsync()
{
    for (int i = 0, n = items.Count; i < n; i++)
    {
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();

        batch.Add(items[i]);

        if (batch.Count == 3 || i >= items.Count - 3)
        {
            List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(3);

            foreach (Item item in batch)
                tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => ProcessItem(item)));

            await Task.WhenAll(tasks.ToArray());

            batch.Clear();
        }

        stopwatch.Stop();

        int elapsed = (int)stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        int delay = (3000) - elapsed;

        if (delay > 0)
            await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
}
```

The only benefit would be that you don't block the `ProcessItems` thread with `Task.WaitAll()` and `Thread.Sleep()`, as @usr pointed out in his answer. Whether to take this approach or `Parallel.ForEach` one probably depends on the running environment of your code. `Async/await` won't make your code run faster, but it will improve its scalability for server-side execution, because it may take less threads to run, so more clients could be served.

Note also that now `ProcessItemsAsync` is itself an async task, so to keep the flow of the code which calls it unchanged, you'd need to call it like this:

```
ProcessItemsAsync().Wait();
```

Which is a blocking call on its own and may kill the advantage of `async` we just gained. Whether you can completely eliminate blocks like this in your app or not, largely depends on the rest of the app's workflow.