# Is there a way to organise an IEnumerable into batches in column-major format using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

In several of my most recent projects, I've found the need to divide a single collection up into `m` batches of `n` elements.

There is an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414347/how-to-loop-through-ienumerable-in-batches) that suggests using morelinq's `Batch` method.  That is my preferred solution (no need to re-invent the wheel and all that).

While the `Batch` method divides the input up in row-major format, would it also be possible to write a similar extension that divides the input up in column-major format?  That is, given the input

```
{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 }
```

you would call `ColumnBatch(4)`, generating an output of

```
{
    { 1, 4, 7, 10 },
    { 2, 5, 8, 11 },
    { 3, 6, 9, 12 }
}
```

Does morelinq already offer something like this?

UPDATE: I'm going to change the convention slightly.  Instead of using an input of `4`, I'll change it to `3` (the number of batches rather than the batch size).

The final extension method will have the signature

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> ToColumns<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int numberOfColumns)
```

which should be clear to whoever is implementing the method, and does not require multiple enumerations.

Comment: This would mean you'd have to either materialize the whole enumeration or enumerate it multiple times. Either way, it seems like a strange thing to do with an enumeration.

Comment: It's not that strange.  Fortran is built on column major format.

Comment: I doubt Fortran has any notion of .NET IEnumerable<T>, yield and deferred execution. It would work well on any materialized type like array, but on a basic IEnumerable, it would be strange, because it would enumerate multiple times and/or materialize it.

Comment: Maybe if I change the convention so that an input of 3 would generate the same output, that would avoid the multiple enumeration.

Comment: `which should be clear to whoever is implementing the method, and does not require multiple enumerations.`  It is *impossible* to solve the problem without either iterating the source multiple times, or materializing the entire query into a single collection before yielding any items (so that that collection can be iterated multiple times).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int[] arr = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12 };
int i=0;
var result = arr.GroupBy(x => i++ % 3).Select(g => g.ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: Now add 13 to the end of the array and watch this break.  That's why you shouldn't use magic numbers.

Comment: +1, I like this solution more, expect closure but it is ok in this case

Comment: @L.B Then add 13, 14, 15, 16 and *still* watch it break.  A hard coded `3` here is wrong.

Comment: @Servy I think OP can get what is meant in that answer.

Comment: So apparently you don't care that it doesn't solve the problem, so long as it works for the single example provided.  That it doesn't work for any other is irrelevant.

Comment: Still, that is the point nvoigt is making.  In the form I put the question, you'd call it with an input of 4, and to get the 3 you'd need to divide the size of the array by the input; hence the multiple enumeration.

Comment: So you care about solving the problem, but you don't care about a comment that demonstrates that you have a bug in your solution to the problem.

Comment: @Servy What do you mean by "break" in your comments?

Comment: @JonSenchyna Return improper results.  This code says, "create 3 batches of size N" while the requirements state "create M batches of size 4".  If there are 9-12 items in the collection this just *coincidentally* works, because 4 columns will result in 3 batches for those values.  For a collection of any other size it is wrong.

Comment: @Servy The question was changed to create N batches.  Due to that, this code create the appropriate results (assuming N is 3).  From there, it's simply a matter of replacing 3 with a variable.