# Reading text file where line occurs every nth character

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to read textfile using streamreader like this:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(FileName, Encoding.Default))
{
   string text = sr.ReadToEnd();
   string[] lines = text.Split('**Every 8th |**');

   foreach(string line in lines)
   {
     .....
   }
}
```

My text file contains values divided by "|". Every 8 "|" contains new group of values which I need to work with. For example I have this:

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11....
```

What I need is

```
1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8
9|10|11....
```

Is it somehow possible to manage this? Regular expressions perhaps? My text file contains hundreds of "|".

Comment: Any reason why you want to use StreamReader?

Comment: Yes, there are no line breaks. Everything is in one line. Don't know why, but I can't change the structure of this file, it's been given to me like this :/

Comment: @helb - No reason, just looked like good idea to me. If you have better idea how to read a file and have a group of values every 8th "|", tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to get a `string[]` for every "pseudo-line":

```
string text = File.ReadAllText(FileName, Encoding.Default);
string[] fields = text.Split('|');
IEnumerable<string[]> lines = fields
    .Select((f, i) => new { Field = f, Index = i })
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 8)
    .Select(g => g.Select(x => x.Field).ToArray());

foreach(string[] lineFields in lines)
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", lineFields));
```

Comment: Very good, following the same line of thought but you are faster

Comment: This is fine as long as the file is not too large, i.e suitable for `ReadAllText`, if you are looking for performance, something along these lines should be considered http://stackoverflow.com/a/15414467/659190, See may answer for specialization to this problem.

Comment: Tim: great minds think alike - I came up with the same answer independently - removing mine now.

Comment: Well, thank you very much, this seems to be working. Never used construction like this before. Only thing which could be improved is time what it takes to process whole file. Around 2 minutes :)

Comment: @JacobH: how large is the file? If you don't need that array you could also remove the `ToArray` inside. That would be more efficient.  You haven't mentioned what you want to do with the result. If performance is very important and you don't need to process the whole file you should use Jodrell's approach.

Comment: Performance is not that important for me. This will run as a background scheduled task every 1 hour. What I will do with it is to update some columns in database. So this solution is useful for me. My file has around 2MB.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is very large or you want to chunk in different sizes you might prefer something more generic.

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> ReadFileInChunks(
        string fileName,
        char[] separators,
        int chunkSize)
{
    string[] bucket = null;
    var count = 0;

    foreach(var item in SplitFile(fileName, sperators))
    {
        if (bucket == null)
        {
            bucket = new string[chunkSize]
        }

        bucket[count++] = item;

        if (count != size)
        {
            continue;
        }

        yield return bucket;
        bucket = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    // Alternatively, throw an exception if bucket != null
    if (bucket != null)
    {           
        yield return bucket.Take(count); 
    }
}

private IEnumerable<string> SplitFile(
        string FileName,
        char[] separators)
{
    var check = new HashSet<int>(seperators.Select(c => (int)c);
    var buffer = new StringBuilder();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(FileName))
    {
        var next = reader.Read();
        while(next != -1)
        {
            if (check.Contains(next))
            {
                yield return buffer.ToString();
                buffer.Clear();
                continue;
            }

            buffer.Append((char)next);

            next = reader.Read();
        }   
    }

    if (buffer.Length > 0)
    {
        yield return buffer.ToString();
    }
}
```

This will read your file one `char` at a time, good if the file is large, not bad if it isn't. It lazily yields the groups in a size you specify.

```
foreach (var row in ReadFileInChunks(FileName, new[] { '|' }, 8))
{
    foreach (var item in row)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or, if you really wan to re-join the values,

```
var results = ReadFileInChunks(FileName, new[] { '|' }, 8).Select(row =>
    string.Join("|", row));
```

Comment: @JacobH added the "blue chip" lazy streaming solution to my answer