# Creating Collection dynamically in C#

Tags: c#

I have an application that will continuously taking user's input and store the input in a `List` of `class ItemsValue`

How am I going to make it so that once the collection reaches 1000 counts, it will "stop" and a new collection will be created and so on.

For example:

```
List<ItemsValue> collection1 = new List<ItemsValue>();
//User input will be stored in `collection1`
if (collection1.count >= 1000)
    //Create a new List<ItemsVales> collection2, 
    //and the user input will be stored in collection2 now.
    //And then if collection2.count reaches 1000, it will create collection3. 
    //collection3.count reaches 1000, create collection4 and so on.
```

Comment: You can make list of collections. But what's the original purpose?

Comment: Why? Why not just add into same collection?

Comment: [XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Why not just use Take and Skip?

Comment: @Liam definitely.  This completely sounds like I have a solution to a problem, help me with my solution, not the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to loop through IEnumerable in batches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414347/how-to-loop-through-ienumerable-in-batches)

Comment: No, we need to temporary store the data in the list then transfer the data into the next application.

Comment: If someone were to look at the question or at any of the answer without reading everything on this page first and use their intuition they would simply state: _Hey ! There's no way that the if statement will ever be true_ or .. _The index access operation [collections.Count - 1] will also throw an exception_. So please: don't be hasty, split the various pieces of code into their rightful places, explain the "event oriented" nature of the operations that are executed against the collection/collections. @Liam: this most surely is an XY problem (+1)

Comment: @Liam It is not my intention to make this an XY problem. I have a job with a specific requirement, it is not up to me to question my clients about their decisions, even if their request sometimes make no sense, but I'm stuck with the Y.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why, but you want a "list of lists":  `List<List<ItemsValue>>`.

```
List<List<ItemsValue>> collections = new List<List<ItemsValue>>();
collections.Add(new List<ItemsValue>());

collections.Last().Add(/*user input*/);

if (collections.Last().Count >= 1000) collections.Add(new List<ItemsValue>());
```

Comment: Looks like we all answered at the same time! Yours seems most concise, so you get my vote.

Comment: Yeah, but your code and @Selman22's code are the only ones which don't throw an exception. +1s

Answer (score 3):

I think you need `List<List<ItemsValue>>`

```
List<List<ItemsValue>> mainCollection = new List<List<ItemsValue>>();
int counter = 0;
if (counter == 0) mainCollection.Add(new List<ItemsValue>());

if(mainCollection[counter].Count < 1000) mainCollection[counter].Add(item);

else 
{
    mainCollection.Add(new List<ItemsValue>());
    counter++;
    mainCollection[counter].Add(item);
}
```

I don't know how is the rest of your code look like,but I would make that *counter* static.

Answer (score 3):

Use a list of collections. If you have fixed size you can use a array instead of a list.

```
List<List<ItemsValue>> collections = new List<List<ItemsValue>>({new List<ItemsValue>()});
if(collections[collections.Count- 1].Count >= 1000)
{
   var newCollection = new List<ItemsValue>();
   // do what you want with newCollection
   collections.Add(newCollection);
}
```

Comment: You can condense your if statement's body to collections.Add(new List<ItemsValue>()) without losing any real readability.

Comment: It's not for readability, it's more for doing things with the new List.

Comment: Ah I see. Although you could easily get that new list by simply going collections.Last() later.

Comment: Yup..nothing wrong with both approaches.. Cheers :)

Comment: Kudos for the compiler error in `collections[collections.Count - 1] >= 1000`, for the irrefutable `IndexOutOfBoundsException` should the code actually compile and for the upvoters' enthusiasm. This is nothing personal: The same goes for the question and the other N-1 answers.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
List<List<ItemsValue>> collections = new List<List<ItemsValue>>({new List<ItemsValue>()});

if(collections[collections.Count-1].Count >= 1000)
{
    collections.Add(new List<ItemsValue>());
}
```

Use the above if statement when you're adding an item to collections. To add an item to collections, use the following:

```
collections[collections.Count-1].Add(yourItem);
```