# How to build batches/buckets with linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, batch-processing, bucket

I need to create batches from a lazy enumerable with following requirements:

- Memory friendly: items must be lazy loaded even within each batch (`IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>`, excludes solution building arrays)
- the solution must not enumerate twice the input (excludes solutions with `Skip()` and `Take()`)
- the solution must not iterate through the entire input if not required (exclude solutions with `GroupBy`)

---

The question is similar but more restrictive to followings:

- [How to loop through IEnumerable in batches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414347/how-to-loop-through-ienumerable-in-batches)
- [Create batches in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Originally posted by @Nick_Whaley in [Create batches in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq), but not the best response as the question was formulated differently:

Try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Bucketize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int bucketSize)
{
    var enumerator = items.GetEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        yield return GetNextBucket(enumerator, bucketSize);
}

private static IEnumerable<T> GetNextBucket<T>(IEnumerator<T> enumerator, int maxItems)
{
    int count = 0;
    do
    {
        yield return enumerator.Current;

        count++;
        if (count == maxItems)
            yield break;

    } while (enumerator.MoveNext());
}
```

The trick is to pass the old-fashion enumerator between inner and outer enumeration, to enable continuation between two batches.