# StackExchange.Redis Scan x amount of keys

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a redis db that has thousands of keys and I'm currently running the following line to get all the keys:

```
string[] keysArr = keys.Select(key => (string)key).ToArray();
```

But because I have a lot of keys this takes a long time. I want to limit the number of keys being read. So I'm trying to run an execute command where I get 100  keys at a time:

```
var keys = Redis.Connection.GetDatabase(dbNum).Execute("scan", 0, "count", 100);
```

This command successfully runs the command, however unable to access the the value as it is private, and unable to cast it even though RedisResult classs provides a explicit cast to it:

```
public static explicit operator string[] (RedisResult result);
```

Any ideas to get x amount of keys at a time from redis?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the .Take() method, outlined by Microsoft [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Returns a specified number of contiguous elements from the start of a
>   sequence.

It would look something like this:

```
//limit to 100
var keysArr = keys.Select(key => (string)key).Take(100).ToArray();
```

Comment: How would I get the next hundred? from the scan command you get a hash for the next query

Comment: @Person you would need to implement a paging `.Skip()` routine, like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414347/how-to-loop-through-ienumerable-in-batches

Comment: using skip and take here to get the pages is ... frankly ... going to be very bad in this scenario; that intent cannot be expressed to the server, so you're implementing a triangular query (meaning: the first items are cheap, the next page is more expensive, and so on ... until the last page is absurdly expensive). This is not a good way to solve this problem *in this specific case*

Comment: @MarcGravell I think it depends on the scope of the desired output. It's not necessarily bad, if you only need a few hundred.

Answer (score 12):

SE.Redis has a `.Keys()` method on `IServer` API which fully encapsulates the semantics of `SCAN`. If possible, *just use this method*, and consume the data 100 at a time. It is usually pretty easy to write a batching function, i.e.

```
ExecuteInBatches(server.Keys(), 100, batch => DoSomething(batch));
```

with:

```
public void ExecuteInBatches<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize,
        Action<List<T>> action)
{
    List<T> batch = new List<T>();
    foreach(var item in source) {
        batch.Add(item);
        if(batch.Count == batchSize) {
             action(batch);
             batch = new List<T>(); // in case the callback stores it
        }
    }
    if (batch.Count != 0) {
        action(batch); // any leftovers
    }
}
```

The enumerator will worry about advancing the cursor.

---

You *can* use `Execute`, but: that is a lot of work! Also, `SCAN` makes no gaurantees about how many will be returned per page; it can be zero - it can be 3 times what you asked for. It is ... guidance only.

Incidentally, the reason that the cast fails is because `SCAN` *doesn't return* a `string[]` - it returns an array of two items, the first of which is the "next" cursor, the second is the keys. So maybe:

```
var arr = (RedisResult[])server.Execute("scan", 0);
var nextCursor = (int)arr[0];
var keys = (RedisKey[])arr[1];
```

But all this is doing is re-implementing `IServer.Keys`, the hard way (and significantly less efficiently - `ServerResult` is *not* the ideal way to store data, it is simply *necessary* in the case of `Execute` and `ScriptEvaluate`).

Comment: Instead of `(int)arr[0];` should the cursor value in the `RedisResult` array be cast to `Int64`? I think that would be consistent with `IScanningResult.Cursor` being an `Int64`. (Bless my heart, I am trying to use `ExecuteCommand` to use `SCAN` directly).

Comment: @StephenSwensen quite possibly; actually, thinking about it there is also a case for using `string` - IIRC there was a redis cluster proxy (which may now be abandoned) which makes that value non-integer (although this would have come about *after* this answer)

Comment: Why not simply use the built-in 'pageSize' parameter that server.Keys method accepts? Will your implementation of `foreach(var item in source)` load one item from Redis at a time, rather than the entire batchSize at a time?

Comment: @BornToCode because that is used for the `SCAN ... COUNT` usage - see the note starting "Also, `SCAN` makes no guarantees..." (context: I'm the main author of SE.Redis)

Comment: @MarcGravell Thank you for the clarification regarding SCAN .. COUNT. But won't your implementation in the answer (of `foreach(var item in source)`) load one item from Redis at a time, rather than the entire batchSize at a time?

Comment: @BornToCode no; that's a custom iterator over successive pages of results from SCAN, simply exposed via the familiar enumerator API; additionally, to reduce latency overheads, it is also asynchronously fetching the next page while you read the current page. Quite a lot of things going on behind that simple-looking API.