# What does "Access to disposed closure" mean?

Tags: c#, closures, resharper

I have the following code:

```
public void DequeueRecipe(AuthIdentity identity, params Guid[] recipeIds)
{
   using (var session = GetSession())
   {
      var recipes = (from r in recipeIds select new Models.Recipes {RecipeId = r}).ToArray();

      var dbRecipes = session.QueryOver<Models.QueuedRecipes>()
         .Where(Expression.Eq("UserId", identity.UserId))
         .Where(Expression.InG("Recipe", recipes))
         .List<Models.QueuedRecipes>();

      using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
      {
         dbRecipes.ForEach(r => session.Delete(r)); // <-- Warning
         transaction.Commit();
      }
   }
}
```

reSharper is giving me the warning:

> Access to disposed closure

On the line:

```
dbRecipes.ForEach(r => session.Delete(r));
```

(The `session` variable is underlined as the culprit).

While it's true the `ForEach` method takes a lamba expression which creates a closure around the variable `session`, I don't see a way where it would possibly be disposed when this code is executed.  Perhaps reSharper thinks `ForEach` might execute some sort of task in parallel, or save that `Action<>` for a later time, thus technically it might be disposed while the anonymous function is still reachable in memory.

Am I safe the ignore this warning?  Is there a way I can reformat my code to prevent this warning from appearing?  Is there indeed a danger presented by this code?

I'm used to reSharper being smarter than me, so I'd like to understand exactly what's going on.

Comment: unrelated: isn't the transaction begin/commit the responsibility of the Delete()?. Is it possible/correct to perform a Delete() outside of a transaction (assuming it has multiple actions [tables])?

Comment: @MitchWheat - Agreed, I can remove the transaction since it will all be committed when the session is disposed.  I've been reworking my session code, so that's a remnant from my earlier architecture.

Comment: I've also gotten this error when using this Batch code snippet for grouping an IEnumerable into batches of size x: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44505349/1040437 My boss saw the warning in Resharper and flipped out.  But as best as I can tell, this is entirely safe code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `session` is wrapped in a using statement, and the LINQ execution could be defered until it is enumerated.

Resharper is warning that this could result in an exception, because by the time `dbRecipes` is enumerated, the `session` could have have been disposed.

I'll be honest: I'm not sure the above code could ever fail in the way warned about.

Comment: `ForEach` should immediately enumerate `dbRecipes`, right?  So nothing should be deferred.

Comment: Wouldn't you consider that a false warning on ReSharper's part then? Could `session` really be disposed in that code? I've never seen my code behave that way. From my understand of the `using` statement ReSharper is just wrong.

Comment: what happens if you add a .ToList() to evaluate dbrecipes?

Comment: @MitchWheat - The warning goes away if I do that.  So reSharper is smart enough to know that the list is definitely enumerated at that time, but isn't smart enough to see that `dbRecipes` is a `Guid[]` and thus enumeration cannot be deferred anyway.

Comment: I think it is just erring on the side of caution. Plus does it know what .List() is?

Comment: @MitchWheat - Oh nevermind, `dbRecipes` is a NHibernate object.  reSharper probably knows of the .NET Linq extensions but doesn't know that .List` will enumerate the dataset.  Interesting.

Comment: Interestingly enough, the warning *also* goes away if I change the line to: `dbRecipes.ForEach(session.Delete);`