# Return item 1 to 3 and 4 to 6 and 7 to 9 in a grouped object with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have this collection:

```
[bla1,blubb2,hello3,salve4,adios5,bye6,mucha7,arrividerci8,bonsoir9,hello10,bah11]
```

I would like to return a collection of T where T has a List with these 3 strings max.

```
bla1, blubb2, hello3,

salve4, adios5, bye6

mucha7, arrividerci8,bonsoir9

hello10,bah11
```

These are no 4 objects each having a list with max. 3 items

Comment: Did you try anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you want:

```
List<List<string>> groups = inputList.Select((e, idx) => new { Item = e, Idx = idx })
    .GroupBy(p => p.Idx / 3)
    .Select(grp => grp.Select(p => p.Item).ToList())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] arr = new[] { "bla1", "blubb2", "hello3", "salve4", "adios5", "bye6", "mucha7", "arrividerci8", "bonsoir9", "hello10", "bah11" };
int cnt=0;
var lists = arr.GroupBy(x => cnt++ / 3)
                .Select(g => g.ToList())
                .ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (avalable from NuGet) extension [`Batch`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Batch.cs):

```
string[] source = { "bla1", "blubb2", "hello3", "salve4", "adios5" };
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<string>> result = source.Batch(3);
```

This extension batches source sequence into sized buckets.

If you don't want to use MoreLINQ library, you can use just [their implementation of Batch extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq/13731823#13731823) or solution by Timothy.

Answer (score 1):

(Use [Sergey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22261538/1828879) if you don't mind the MoreLINQ dependency.)

## Extension Method

```
public static IEnumerable<List<T>> GroupSequential<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, int groupSize, bool includePartialGroups = true)
{
    if (groupSize < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(
            "groupSize", groupSize, "Must have groupSize >= 1.");
    }
    var group = new List<T>(groupSize);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        group.Add(item);
        if (group.Count == groupSize)
        {
            yield return group;
            group = new List<T>(groupSize);
        }
    }
    if (group.Any() && (includePartialGroups || group.Count == groupSize))
    {
        yield return group;
    }
}
```

## Usage

```
IEnumerable<string> values = ...;
IEnumerable<List<string>> groups = values.GroupSequential(3);
```

Comment: You either really fast, or there should be link to original answer :)

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy I am the original (although I'm sure others have made the same functionality). :) It's a utility method I use.

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy they answered your comment in 21 seconds... id lean on the fast side. ha

Comment: OK then, you are really fast :)