# Chopping string with LINQ

Tags: c#, string, linq

I would like to use LINQ to achieve this:

Having a string like `"abcdefghijk"` and a "chunk size" of 3,

- The LINQ query should return

  ```
  {"abc", "def", "ghi", "jk" }
  ```
- With chunk size of 4:

  ```
  {"abcd", "efgh", "ijk" }
  ```

I'm almost sure that I would have to use TakeWhile, or Zip, but I don't know how to use them!

Comment: Take, TakeWhile, and Skip work in singular fashion, not repetitively, I believe.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create batches in linq](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Batch` method from [`MoreLinq`](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library:

```
var chunks = str.Batch(4).Select(x => new string(x.ToArray()).ToList();
```

This can also be done with `GroupBy` but the code won't look that pretty:

```
var chunks = str
          .Select((x,idx) => new { x, idx })
          .GroupBy(c => c.idx / 4)
          .Select(g => new string(g.Select(c => c.x).ToArray()))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: Note that this version of batching fully buffers so if you are looking at huge string sizes it's going to be slow.