# Creating a bootstrap row for every 2 items when looping through a list in a Razor View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have an IEnumerable of Video objects as my Razor View's Model.

```
@model IEnumerable<VideoViewModel>
```

I am trying to make it so every 2 videos will be inside of a bootstrap row. The first video of the two will be in the first col-md-6 and the second video of the two will be in the second col-md-6.

**Here is an example of what I am looking to do with a razor foreach loop:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        First video in model
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Second video in model
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Third video in model
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Fourth video in model
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Fifth video in model
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        Sixth video in model
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no need for a linq extension method. You can do this simply in the view using a `for` loop and a modulus operator `if (i % 2 == 0)` to start a new `<div class="row">`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to batch your list and then loop through the batches. You can create an extension method like this (from [Create batches in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq)):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Batch<TSource>(
                  this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size)
{
    TSource[] bucket = null;
    var count = 0;

    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        if (bucket == null)
            bucket = new TSource[size];

        bucket[count++] = item;
        if (count != size)
            continue;

        yield return bucket;

        bucket = null;
        count = 0;
    }

    if (bucket != null && count > 0)
        yield return bucket.Take(count);
}
```

Then you can run through the batches like this:

```
@foreach(var batch in Model.Batch(2))
{
    <div class="row">
    @foreach(var item in batch)
    {
        <div class="col-md-6">
            Fifth video in model
        </div>

    }
    </div>
}
```

Comment: This is a neater function for doing the batching: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6362642/249879

Comment: Looks neater, but is not as efficient as the above.

Comment: @Kenneth Thank you very much for this answer. I just created a static class called LinqExtensions and added the extension method you gave. Then in my razor the code you supplied worked perfectly. It is ashame I am not able to install moreLinq in an asp.net core project. I never know where I should be placing an extension method class in an asp.net mvc project so I just threw it in my Core/Models folder...