# c# loop take large record collection, process 20 records at a time

Tags: c#

I am stuck on how to take a large collection of 2500 or more records in a LIST and process 20 records at a time until all of them are processed.

```
LIST<MyRecords> newRecords = object.getNewRecordsToProcecss();

if (newRecords.Count > 0)
{
// loop and process 20 at a time

}
```

I did google this but not sure how to implement linq split.

I am stuck. I can't think of the logic to process into smaller batches. Is there a way in LINQ or something.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: I think you need to look at TAKE() and SKIP()

Comment: You can use `Skip(x).Take(y)` to take a number of records skipping ones that have already been processed. You can run concurrent `Task`s to perform the processing in parallel

Comment: You can play with index as well if you don't know linq.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq