# Microsoft Face API: Not working for bulk images

Tags: c#, asynchronous, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to fetch faces from images inside a folder. If there are relatively less number of images, it works but if there are huge number of images(around 1500) it raises an error after processing around 10 images.
"MakeAnalysisRequest" is the function that sends the request to Microsoft FaceAPI. This function also add "faceId" to the list because I need this list only after processing of all the images is finished. That's why there is this piece of code in the function

```
foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    tasks.Add(MakeAnalysisRequest(file.FullName, file.Name, delay, subscriptionKey, endPointURL));
}

//Waiting for "MakeAnalysisRequest" to finish.
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

If I process around 100 images, everything works fine. However if I try to run the process for around 1500 images it fails(raises "There was an error while saving the file!"). The Exception only says "Aggregate Exception". Handling "Aggregate" exception also do not reveal anything in inner exception. Here is the complete code(Variables are not included. Only relevant code for readability):

```
public void ProcessImages(string imageFolderPath)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(imageFolderPath);
        //Only jpeg|jpg files are needed for the process. Filtering the images in folder. 
        string[] extensions = new[] { ".jpg", ".jpeg" };
        FileInfo[] files = dInfo.GetFiles().Where(f => extensions.Contains(f.Extension.ToLower())).ToArray();
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        foreach (FileInfo file in files)
        {
            tasks.Add(MakeAnalysisRequest(file.FullName, file.Name, delay, subscriptionKey, endPointURL));
        }

        //Waiting for "MakeAnalysisRequest" to finish.
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        //faceIds are generated in MakeAnalysisRequest function.
        CreateFaceGroups(faceIds);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There was an error while saving the file! ");
    }
}

static async Task MakeAnalysisRequest(string imageFilePath, string fileName, int delay, string subscriptionKey, string endPointURL)
{
    //To control the numberof requests sent per second. Client does not allow more than 10 per second.
    await Task.Delay(delay);

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    HttpResponseMessage response;

    // Request body. Posts a locally stored JPEG image.
    byte[] byteData = GetImageAsByteArray(imageFilePath);

    using (ByteArrayContent content = new ByteArrayContent(byteData))
    {
        content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

        // Execute the REST API call.
        response = await client.PostAsync(endPointURL, content);

        // Get the JSON response.
        string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(contentString))
        {
            try
            {
                //Converting the response to DTO class object.
                List<RootObject> objRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<RootObject>>(contentString);
                foreach (var obj in objRoot)
                {
                    if (obj != null)
                    {
                        objFaceIdImage.Add(new FaceIdImageLink { faceId = obj.faceId, imageName = fileName });
                        faceIds.Add(obj.faceId);
                        //Based on the coordinates creating face image by cropping the source image.
                        CropImage(fileName, imageFilePath, obj.faceRectangle.left, obj.faceRectangle.top, obj.faceRectangle.width, obj.faceRectangle.height, obj.faceId);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                var a = ex;
            }
        }
        else
            ReStart("No faces found in the images!");
    }
}
```

Can't find out where the issue is!

Comment: The aggregate exception will give you more details, that's the point of having it. It's not in the `InnerException` property though, try the `InnerExceptions`

Comment: @DavidG InnerExceptions has count 610 and all it says is "A task is cancelled". I don't see anything else relevant.

Comment: I'm sure there's more information than that in there. However, looking at your code, you have a peculiar way of ensuring there are never more than 10 requests per second, I'm pretty sure that's not going to work. Why not just group the images into batches of 10 and process them all immediately, then when they're complete, make sure at least 1 second has passed?

Comment: @DavidG you are absolutely right. The issue is in the number of requests sent per second. Can you please suggest a better way to send no more than 10 requests per second? Grouping images will require additional task. For this I will have to buy the time and I am not sure if my client can delay this. Is there anything that can be done here itself?

Comment: @DavidG I will be trying System.Threading.Thread.Sleep instead of await Task.Delay(delay);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code to limit your processing to 10 requests per second doesn't work. In fact all it does is ensure that every request is delayed by `delay` and then they all fire at once. A safer solution would be to do the processing in batches and only delay if a batch was done in less than a second. For example (untested code) and using this handy batching extension method from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13731823/1663001):

```
public void ProcessImages(string imageFolderPath)
{
    FileInfo[] files = ...

    foreach (var batch in files.Batch(10))
    {
        var stopWatch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        //Process the files as before, but now only 10 at a time
        ProcessBatch(batch);

        stopWatch.Stop();

        //If less than 1 second has passed, let's hang around until it has
        if(stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 1000)
        {
            //Probably don't use Thread.Sleep here, but you get the idea
            Thread.Sleep(1000 - (int)stopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
    }
}

private void ProcessBatch(IEnumerable<FileInfo> batch)
{
    //Process the batch as before
    var tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach (FileInfo file in batch)
    {
        //Remove the 'delay' parameter as it's no longer needed
        tasks.Add(MakeAnalysisRequest(file.FullName, file.Name, 
            subscriptionKey, endPointURL));
    }

    //Waiting for "MakeAnalysisRequest" to finish.
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
```