# How to Serialize a class object and save it on to Multiple XML files

Tags: c#, xml, entity-framework, serialization, xml-serialization

I have an Employee class like below

```
 public class Employee
    {
        public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime DOB { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using Entity Framework to retrieve the Employee data from the database like below

```
using (var dbContext = new EmployeeEntities())
{
    List<Employee> employeeList = new List<Employee>();
    employeeList = dbContext.employee.Select(x => new Employee
                                        {
                                            EmployeeID = x.EmployeeID,
                                            Name = x.Name,
                                            Age = x.Age,
                                            DOB = x.DOB
                                        }).ToList();
}
```

And then i serialize the list and save it as an XML file.

```
if (employeeList.Count > 0)
{
     XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>));
     TextWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("D:\\Employee.xml", true);
     mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, employeeList);
     myWriter.Close();
}
```

My requirement here is to save the result set to Multiple XML files based on the page size that i specify. E.g if the Employee table contains 536 rows and my page size is 100, then i should save it in 6 XML files containing 100,100,100,100,100 and 36 rows respectively. How do i achieve this using entity framework??

Comment: I would suggest `.Skip()` and `.Take()`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41272110/8951109

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the past I've done this with this `Batch` extension method:

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    /// <summary> 
    /// Splits the values in an enumerable by position into batches of the specified size 
    /// </summary> 
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Batch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, int batchSize)
    {
        using (var e = items.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e.MoveNext()) // check before entering the loop 
            {
                yield return BatchOf(e, batchSize);
            }
        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<T> BatchOf<T>(IEnumerator<T> e, int batchSize)
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0 && !e.MoveNext()) // already checked once before entering the loop / so only check on subsequent iterations 
            {
                yield break;
            }
            yield return e.Current;
        }
    }
}
```

Then it's simple enough to use:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var batch in employeeList.Batch(100))
{
    XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>));
    TextWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter($"D:\\Employee{i++}.xml", true);
    mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, batch.ToList());
    myWriter.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.Skip()` and `.Take()` to do the trick.

`.Take()` will take the defined amount of items from the list, if there are less, it will take all.
`.Skip()` will skip the amount defined.

By having the `tmp` variable, you can work the `employeeList` off and save each file.

```
  if (employeeList.Count > 0)
        {
            int take = 100;
            int i = 0;
            while (employeeList.Any())
            {
                i++;
                var tmp = employeeList.Take(take)ToList();
                employeeList = employeeList.Skip(take).ToList();
                XmlSerializer mySerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Employee>));
                TextWriter myWriter = new StreamWriter("D:\\Employee"+i+".xml", true);
                mySerializer.Serialize(myWriter, tmp);
                myWriter.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: But note that performance may suffer if you have lots of records... https://www.make-awesome.com/2010/08/batch-or-partition-a-collection-with-linq/

Comment: I am getting the following exception if i follow this approach.          Unable to cast object of type '<SkipIterator>d__31`1[Employee]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Employee]'.

Comment: @raja_89 strange, it complied just fine for me. I've added .ToList(), that should fix the type mismatch.