# How to limit the number of text strings arrays to 15

Tags: c#

How to limit the lines pulled from the document to **15** lines at a time. Right now it displays all the lines at once. thanks.

```
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(
        @"C:\Users\chri749y\Documents\Skrive til fil\Testprogram.txt");

    foreach (string line in lines) {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", line);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to read only 15 lines at once from the file (ie to replace your File.ReadAllLines call) OR how to process all the lines in blocks of 15?

Comment: @tolanj That's the question. Dmitry interpreted it as the former, and I interpreted it as the latter. I read "at a time" meaning "within the loop" (i.e. "I'm working with a big document and don't want it all in memory at once.")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create batches in linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq)

Answer (score 10):

If you want *top* `15` lines only, try [Take](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb503062%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (*Linq*) which is specially designed for this:

```
var lines = System.IO.File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\chri749y\Documents\Skrive til fil\Testprogram.txt")
  .Take(15);
```

In case you want *batch processing* i.e. get `0 .. 14` lines then `15 .. 29` lines etc.

```
// Split input into batches with at most "size" items each
private static IEnumerable<T[]> Batch<T>(IEnumerable<T> lines, int size) {
  List<T> batch = new List<T>(size);

  foreach (var item in lines) {
    if (batch.Count >= size) {
      yield return batch.ToArray();

      batch.Clear();
    }

    batch.Add(item);
  }

  if (batch.Count > 0)   // tail, possibly incomplete batch
    yield return batch.ToArray();
}
```

Then

```
var batches = Batch(System.IO.File
  .ReadLines(@"C:\Users\chri749y\Documents\Skrive til fil\Testprogram.txt"),
               15);

foreach (var batch in batches) { // Array with at most 15 items
  foreach (var line in batch) {  
    ... 
  }
}
```

Comment: If you call twice in a row `System.IO.File.ReadLines(MyFile).Take(15)` will you get **first** the 15 first line, **then** the lines 16 to 30 ?

Comment: @Cid: No; you'll get top `15` lines *twice*; if you want to *skip* 15 lines and only then take 15 lines - `.Skip(15).Take(15)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this become easy to implement if you want to get lines block by block, although heavy to process with large files, using `.Skip(BlockNumber++ * BlockSize).Take(BlockSize)`

Comment: @Cid: In case of files, `.Skip(n).Take(m)` is *inefficient*: we constantly re-read the file; I've edited the answer: we should read the file just once and form batches while reading.

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood you correctly, you can do this using `System.IO.File.ReadLines` which lets you stream the file in as an `IEnumerable<string>`. I've created a custom batching function which will read 15 lines at a time.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var lines = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\chri749y\Documents\Skrive til fil\Testprogram.txt");
    foreach (var batch in Batch(lines, 15))
    {
        foreach (var line in batch)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(line);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

This will return a List per `batchSize` (e.g. 15) lines of the file.

```
private IEnumerable<List<T>> Batch<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int batchSize)
{
    if (batchSize < 1)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Batch size must be at least 1.", nameof(batchSize));
    }
    var batch = new List<T>(batchSize);
    foreach (var item in source)
    {
        batch.Add(item);
        if (batch.Count == batchSize)
        {
            yield return batch;
            batch = new List<T>(batchSize);
        }
    }
    if (batch.Any())
    {
        yield return batch;
    }
}
```