# Combine Foreach loop and counter to add dynamically generated html to the beginning and end of every nth row

Tags: c#, foreach, htmlgenericcontrol

I am dynamically generating HtmlGeneric Controls with data in a DataTable. I need to concatenate HTML to the beginning and end of each group of 3. For example, my table looks something like this:

```
Title           Body
------------------------------
Order 1     This is body 1
Order 2     This is body 2
Order 3     This is body 3
Order 4     This is body 4
Order 5     This is body 5
Order 6     This is body 6
```

I'm currently generating HTML like this with no issue:

```
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Order 1</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is body 1</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Order 2</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is body 2</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Order 3</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is body 3</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Order 4</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is body 4</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Order 5</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is body 5</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="card">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">Order 6</h5>
    <p class="card-text">This is body 6</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to combine a foreach loop and a counter to concatenate a div with a card-group class at the beginning and end of every 3 cards like this. Of course, in reality there are a lot more rows than 6.:

```
<div class="card-group">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Order 1</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is body 1</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Order 2</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is body 2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Order 3</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is body 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="card-group">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Order 4</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is body 4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Order 5</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is body 5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">Order 6</h5>
        <p class="card-text">This is body 6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's very simple without the need for concatenating the additional HTML. This is executed in my page load method:

```
DataTable dtCards = GetData();
foreach (DataRow row in dtCards.Rows)
{
    var titleText = row["Title"].ToString();
    var bodyText = row["Body"].ToString();
    CreateDiv(titleText, bodyText); //method to create HmtlGeneric Controls
}
```

I'm assuming I'll need to combine a foreach loop with a counter inside the CreateDiv method but cannot wrap my mind around how exactly that will work out. Especially if there's an odd number of rows - the card-group div would always need a closing tag on the final row.

Comment: Can you split the data in batches ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13731796/create-batches-in-linq)) and surround each batch with your extra markup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shane, what you are essentially doing is Paging through your Rows in your table, so focus on Skip and Take Linq extension methods. Below is a hasty sample

```
void Main()
{
    // Data table that we are trying to page trough 
    List<string> rows = new List<string>() 
    {
        " title1,body1 ",
        " title2,body2 ",
        " title3,body3 ",
        " title4,body4 ",
        " title5,body5 ",
        " title6,body6 ",
        " title7,body7 "
    };
    
    //Result after paging 
    List<string> group = new List<string>();
    
    // Set your page size or pass in as a parameter
    int numberOfObjectsPerPage = 3;
    
    decimal totalRows = rows.Count; 
    int pages = (int) Math.Ceiling(totalRows/numberOfObjectsPerPage);
    
        
    for(int i=0;i<pages;i++)
    {       
            
            string rowText = "";
            
            // Get the rows in that page Focus on the Skip and Take methods
            var tempRows = rows.Skip(i * numberOfObjectsPerPage).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);
            
            // Now foreach page do something here
            foreach(var row in tempRows)
            {
                rowText = rowText + row.ToString();
            }
            
            group.Add("div group" + rowText + "/div" );
            
    };

    group.ForEach( g => 
    {
         Console.WriteLine(g);
    });
}
```

you get something like this.

```
div group title1,body1  title2,body2  title3,body3 /div
div group title4,body4  title5,body5  title6,body6 /div
div group title7,body7 /div
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good way to use two methods, one for creating `start tag` and one for `end tag` if needed, like this:

```
    int counter=0, quantity;//make these global in your class

    public void CreateHtml()
    {
        DataTable dtCards = GetData();
        quantity= dt.Rows.Count;
        foreach (DataRow row in dtCards.Rows)
        {   counter++;
            EndCardGroup();
            StartCardGroup();
            var titleText = row["Title"].ToString();
            var bodyText = row["Body"].ToString();
            CreateDiv(titleText, bodyText); //method to create HmtlGeneric Controls
        }
    }

    private void StartCardGroup()
    {
        if (counter % 3 == 0 || counter == 1)
        {
            //you code to create start 'CardGroup' div
        }
    }

    private void EndCardGroup()
    {
        if (counter %3 == 0 || counter==quantity)
        {
            //you code to create end 'CardGroup' div
        }
    }
```

Of course you can use `for` statment instead of `foreach`. and you can make `DataTable` global to use its `Row.Count` to get rid of `counter` and `quantity`.